# Create TensorFlow Dataset with multiple data sources

Tags: python, mongodb, tensorflow

I am trying to create a TensorFlow Dataset by joining data from 2 different sources. I am trying to replicate the dataset creation from the following paper:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.01984

The dataset is available on BigQuery on the following link:

- https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2008?pli=1&tab=details

Basically I have a CSV file with 3 columns 'Context', 'Response', 'Author', which I read like so:

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
            "data/2007.csv",
            record_defaults=[tf.string, tf.string,tf.string],
            select_cols=[0, 1, 2],
            field_delim=",",
            header=True)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.batch(20)
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

And then I want to add another field 'Persona' to my dataset from a MongoDB based on what the 'Author' field is. I know there is a map function which I can use like this:

```
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=data_map)
```

And implement the data_map function to query mongo to fetch the results.
What I have in mind is something like this:

```
def data_map(context, response, author):
    # iterate author tensor and do pyMongo queries to fetch 'persona's
    return {'Context': context, 
            'Response': response, 
            'Author': author, 
            'Persona': persona}
```

My question is what is an efficient way to do this.

My dataset is more than 1TB big and I need to have the field 'Persona' on Mongo to query it fast. I can't have it on the csv file, because it will become huge (There are many rows with the same author and each author has a Persona with more than 100 sentences each). Should I loop over the Author tensor and query the mongo, and then construct a tensor for 'Persona'? Is there any other more efficient way?